# How to create home url with only domain name?

Tags: html, apache, web

I understand that this is probably a simple question; however, I cannot find a concise answer.

If I have a website named "example.com" how do I get the user to enter only "example.com" and be taken to my page?  As it stands my home page resides at "example.com/home.html," and they must enter exactly "example.com/home.html." Which is incredibly inconvenient.

Comment: It depends on your web server. Apache? IIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using apache, create a `.htaccess` file with the following content

```
DirectoryIndex home.html
```

I do not think you can force users to enter anything :)

Comment: Honestly, I have no clue what it is I am using. I do know that the server runs on linux.  I feel like I should know more about how my site is hosted.

Comment: Yes, as @ÁlvaroG.Vicario says - try upload a .htaccess and see what happends. If it is linux, I am pretty sure it will respond to a .htaccess.

Comment: This should be the correct answer if your host allows you to use your own .htaccess. I know some hosts dont like people to create their own.

Comment: How would I save a file as a .htaccess and where would I put it on my server?

Comment: save it as .htaccess and put it in your root folder most of the time its public_html

Comment: Ok, I went ahead and searched for it in public_html and it says it exists, but won't take me to it.  I'm thoroughly confused though I may be thinking about this waaay to hard.  I tried to upload mine with the    DirectoryIndex home.html and it gives me the option to overwrite it, but I'm slightly apprehensive to do so as I don't know what is in the one already on there.

Comment: I overwrote that previous file now nothing works XD. Restoring now.

Comment: let me guess your using cPanel? I believe there is an option to show hidden (dot) files

Comment: You are correct. I did that and it worked.  After I restored my files it shows that the .htaccess file is empty and now I can't connect to any of the pages :/

Comment: @Fulmetal5, I am very sorry, should have been more instructive :( cant you edit the .htaccess file directly, like with FTP? What webhost / provider is it? Maybe they have a default .htaccess online so the original content can be restored. An empty .htaccess should never be able to block access to files / pages, it is the other way round. But there mau be spme redirection in the default .htaccess - can you please tell the name of the provider?

Comment: It is through freehosting.com and it uses cpanel.

Comment: I may have found the issue..... https://www.freehosting.com/client/serverstatus.php my website resides on customers.freehosting.com

Comment: Yes, customers.freehosting.com seems to be down. But this is really odd, this should have happend at the same time, and it is down for so long. According to freehosting.com alle their account types (free, premium, deluxe or what they are called) should support .htaccess, modrewrite and run on apache.

Comment: I will attempt to test it again once the server comes back up. It may have just been coincidental.

Comment: Ok, I was able to access the website this time.

Comment: The .htaccess file worked wonderfully. I was able to test it and it was successful now that the server is up :D

Comment: @Fulmetal5, very pleased to hear it!! Was feeling kind of bad if you accidentally had screwed your website up because of my suggestion :(

Comment: Well, what you said made sense, and I didn't think it was your fault.  Turns out it was just the stupid servers.  Thanks again for the assistance.  I had never even heard of .htaccess and know very little to none at all about servers.

Answer (score 1):

Rename your home page to `index.html`

Answer (score 0):

rename home.html to index.html (on linux servers) or default.html (on windows servers)

Comment: Because, you know, Windows servers still haven't found a way to overpass the 8+3 filename limit imposed by MS-DOS.

Answer (score -1):

create an index.php file to use as your home page